# Removing a glued down wood stair tread

Tags: stairs, adhesive, removal

I have a wooden stair tread glued down to a ply wood stair frame. The miter cut on the step was just not done right, it would take too much caulk and  I've decided to replace it.

I thought the poor miter cut would be OK before gluing, but now that I'm at it, I'd rather just redo the cut, it's the only step I messed up so I'm OK with it.

Fortunately, there is no riser above the step yet.

How would would go about removing this glued down tread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately if it was glued properly and has fully dried it may be almost impossible to get the tread up. Wood glue is extremely strong (it can actually be even stronger than the bond between the wood fibers).

I don't know what to suggest other than going at it with a demo pry bar. If you are able to get most of it up you can clean up the plywood with a chisel and/or a belt sander.

Comment: Thanks for info, I wound up prying the piece of plywood it was glued to and re-cutting that one. That one was nailed and not obstructed :-P